# How to tell dropwizard-swagger/swagger-ui that there is no request body on a resource method?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, dropwizard

I'm integrating [dropwizard-swagger](https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger) into a large existing project. 
I've got the `Swagger UI` endpoint up and running now, but I'm noticing that it seems adamant that every method must have a body parameter.

Specifically, the first parameter in the method definition that doesn't have an `@ApiParam` annotation gets interpreted as a request body. There doesn't appear to be a way to specify a body parameter, nor does there seem to be a way to exclude parameters from being labelled as such automatically by `Swagger UI`. This means that the "Try it Out" functionality doesn't work for a large portion of the endpoints, as bodies are disallowed by the spec but `Swagger UI` keeps insisting they are present.

For example, consider the below method in the `UserResource` file:

```
@GET
@Path("v1/users/{userId}/subscriptions")
@ApiOperation(value = "Get user subscriptions", notes = "Returns information about the users current and past subscriptions.")
@UserAccessRequired
@RolesAllowed({//a list of appropriate roles})
@Produces(CompanyMediaType.APPLICATION_API_V1_JSON)
public SubscriptionsDTOV1 getSubscriptionsForUser(@Auth DashboardUser dashboardUser, @JooqInject DSLContext database,
                                                  @Context ResourceContext resourceContext,
                                                  @Context ContainerRequestContext crc,
                                                  @ApiParam(value = "ID of user", type = "Integer") @NotNull @UnwrapValidatedValue @PathParam("userId") IntParam userId) {
```

Swagger is interpreting the first parameter, `@Auth DashboardUser dashboardUser`, as being the request body, and generating the below view in `Swagger UI`:

[Swagger UI with a body parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps8ik.png)

Since this is a `GET`, it's not permitted to have a body, and attempting to delete the contents of the body in the `Swagger UI` while testing it out doesn't work, as the field autofills with `{}`.

How do I indicate to `Swagger` that there is no body parameter here and get this to work? Just putting `@ApiParam` in front of the other method parameters doesn't work, as that annotation is ignored if there isn't also a `@QueryParam`/`@PathParam`/etc annotation present.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out adding @ApiParam(hidden=true) seems to have done the trick. I tried this before and didn't get results, must have just had a typo somewhere.

Comment: I have had the same issue and fixed it in the same way, but I supect there should be a better way by using an explicit OAUTH 2 declaration.
The problem is that seem to be available only in OAS 3: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/